# Linear algebra with discrete, ordinal, but non-numeric values?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a series of statements relating various discrete, ordinal, but non-numeric values.  I'd like to reason about those statements intelligently.  Looking at the relationships I want to say that it is a linear algebra problem but I'm not sure you can use linear algebra rules with non-numeric coefficients.

vastly oversimplified example case
I have the following ordinal relationships

```
a < b < c
d < e
```

and the following equations

```
{a, d} = f
{c, e} = g
```

in this case, there is no relationship between, say, a and e.  It's not that the relationship isn't known, it doesn't exist.

I want a formal way of analyzing those equations to say that f < g given that all the components of f are < all the comparable components of g.  Is linear algebra applicable?  Is there a better toolset I should be looking at?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how linear algebra would be relevant here; the "linear" in "linear algebra" doesn't refer to an ordering but rather to linearity in the sense of a function satisfying $f(ax)=af(x)$ and $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for $x,y$ *vectors* and $a$ a *scalar*. Rather, what you're considering here are [**partial orders** (or *posets*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set), and the relevant subject is **order theory** - although partial orders are so ubiquitous in mathematics that you won't need to specifically look at order theory to see them.

Incidentally, your proposed ordering on subsets of a given poset - namely, $A\trianglelefteq B$ iff for each $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, either $a$ and $b$ are incomparable or $a<b$ - isn't very well-behaved. Specifically:

- It's not antisymmetric: if $a$ and $b$ are incomparable then $\{a\}\trianglelefteq \{b\}$ and $\{b\}\trianglelefteq \{a\}$.
- More importantly, it's not *transitive*: suppose we have a partial order with elements $a,b,c$ where $a<b$ and $c$ is incomparable with both $a$ and $b$. Then $\{b\}\trianglelefteq\{c\}\trianglelefteq\{a\}$ but $\{b\}\not\trianglelefteq\{a\}$.

A better notion is to compare all elements at once: say $A\preccurlyeq B$ if for every $a\in A$ and every $b\in B$ we have $a<b$. This still isn't entirely great (if $a<b<c$ then consider $\{a,c\}$ versus $\{a,b,c\}$) but at least it's transitive.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I wasn't fully outlining the problem so it led to some ambiguity.  In my case, a and b and c are things you might compare like say colors (where greater might mean a preference) whereas d and e might be sounds.  So the case where c is comparable to both a and d won't occur.  If such a comparison made any real sense a, c, and d would all be part of one string of comparatives.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll take a look at posets.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a relationship between linear algebra and order.

When Hamilton constructed an algebra with the complex numbers he showed that a real number  is (a,0), i=(0,1) and 0,1)(0,1)=(-1,0).

He constructed these couples from reasoning about continious progression in time, inspired by Kant’s pure intuition - pure time. He lays it out in the essay Algebra as a Science of Pure Time (1835), and associativity and distributivity is a consequence of his conceptual thinking. I am perhaps very late to the party here, but it might be of interest.